# creating convex lens but focal length is not accurate

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, glass, depth-of-field

I made the biconvex lens with the following parameters:
focal length=30 mm
R1=30.4 mm
R2=-30.4 mm
lens diameter=19.1 mm
center thickness=3.1 mm
environment IOR=1
lens IOR=1.515

I set up a 2f optical system But the result is not correct, the focal length differs from the theoretical value by 1.5 times:

[image: I set up a 2f optical system:]

[image: But the result is not correct, the focal length differs from the theoretical value by 1.5 times:]

Comment: Hello :). We're Blender enthusiasts here, not optical engineers. What exactly is your question? What have you tried to solve the problem? You can also add the material setup and the file https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The camera already has a lens on it. Have you accounted for this?